# Storing sorted lists efficiently in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have two sorted lists of the following form:

```
A: 30,31,32,35,39,41,59,71,75,79,81,82,85,...
B: 28,29,33,39,40,41,71,75,79,81,82,83,84,85,86,..
```

That is: list B has most of the elements of list A (but not all) with a few additions. Is there some efficient way by which I may store the two lists in compressed form. I intend to store A completely. And intend to only store the changes in B. Is there some efficient algorithm which exploits this?

Comment: Mergesort the lists and store a field indicating to which list an entry belongs.

Comment: @SergeyL. Can you illustrate that with the help of an example

Comment: I see you have `85` doubled up in list `B`. Can both lists contain repeated elements?

Comment: no that's a mistake..thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @JannatArora Added an answer with a small illustration.

Comment: Just compute the lists of differences (`[1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 18, 12, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3]` for the first list) and store the starting value as well. Then just use any generic compression algorithm on the result, which should be quite effective at detecting repeated runs and using the minimum number of bits

Comment: You may have 3 lists, `common` (which may be computed with `std::set_union`) and `UniqueA` and `UniqueB` which contain unique elements.

Comment: What sort of access patterns will you perform on B? What are the performance requirements, if any, for accessing B?

Comment: How big are these lists? Is it worthwhile doing this?

Comment: @Jarod42 why don't you expand that into an answer? It's better than any of the existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to store your lists merged and have each element identify to which it belongs:

```
[A]1, [B]5, [A, B]16, [A]17, [A, B] 18, ...
```

This can be implemented trivially as an array of structs:

```
struct sorted_list_with_flag_s {
    char membership;
    int value;
}

struct sorted_list_with_flag_s * joined_list;

for (i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    if (joined_list[i].membership & 0x1) { /* joined_list[i].value is in A */}
    if (joined_list[i].membership & 0x2) { /* joined_list[i].value is in B */}
```

Or to save more space have the membership vector separately:

```
char * membership_vector;
int members = 2; // first bit for even bits for A, odd for B
int * joined_list;

for (i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    if (membership_vector[i * members / 8] & (1 << ((i * members) % 8)))
         { /* joined_list[i] is in A */}
    if (membership_vector[(i * members + 1) / 8] & (1 << ((i * members + 1) % 8)))
         { /* joined_list[i] is in B */}
```

Answer (score 0):

For list A, since you store it completely and don't expect to change it, I would use an algorithm like others suggest, storing a base and a list of differences.  In addition, I would scan the A list to determine the deltas and their frequencies, then I would encode the deltas using Huffman codes with the shortest H-codes used on the most frequent deltas.  I would store a mapping table to map delta to H-code.  This assumes the size of your list is very large (a reasonable assumption, since you want to compress it).  That said, looking up a specific number in the list would be less efficient than other storage approaches.

For B, the relationship to A seems irrelevant.  Instead, you just have another sorted list of integers that you expect to change over time.  If storage efficiency is your most important consideration, use the same approach for list A, and pay the performance price with each insert and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You may have 3 lists : `common` (which may be computed with `std::set_union`)
and `UniqueA` and `UniqueB` which contain unique elements of `A` and `B`.

Answer (score -1):

```
28,29,33,39,40,41,59,71,75,79,81,82,83,84,85,85,..
```

is equal to

```
base=28

+0, +1, +4, +6, +1, +1, +18, +12, +4, +4, +2, ..

then each number is described by a few bits. Also they are repeated 
so you can store number of repeatitions at the unused bits if there is any.

if Maximum increment is 15, then any element can be stored as 4 bits. 
If they are repeated, you can use an extra nibble or byte for number of repeats.

You can even use the increment of increment where necessary such as:

+0, +1, +3, +2, -5, -5, +17, -6, -8 ,... so even lesser bits may prove useful.

and remaining bits can be used for more number of repeats or formatting hints.
```